# How to say or spell "for the many"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

How might one accurately state "for the many" in classical/common Latin ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you add a bit more context to what you want to convey with that phrase it will help lead to more accurate suggestions.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "for the many"? Is this *for* in the sense of *on behalf of* or *for the sake of*, or is it in the sense of *to/for*. If it is the former, I think "pro" would be a good preposition to use, but, if the latter, maybe the dative. I assume you want the former. Also, can you be a bit more specific about "the many." I guess that you want this to mean the Roman citizenry, but do you want a more literal translation which would render as *the many [men/people]*, or you do you want it as to represent the lower classes, or something else entirely? Gratiās tibi ago.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Pro multis** or **pro plúribus** would be OK to mean both *for many* or *for the many* (in the sense of *in benefit of the many*). Latin doesn't have definite articles. In a longer text, the function of the article is fulfilled by context or word order.

   The **pluribus** option implies a comparative: *for the very many/for the innumerable*/*for the more*.
2. You could force the sense of the article by adding a demonstrative pronoun, as in

   > *for the many who died* → *for* those *many who died* → **pro *illis* multis qui mortui sunt**.
3. If it is for a motto or an inscription, it's OK to shorten the phrase to **pro illis multis**. It would sound incomplete elsewhere in classical Latin (i.e., in a different context), but I think it sounds well enough in medieval/late Latin. This very pronoun is the precursor of definite articles in Romance languages and at some point it was used almost as one.

**Update:** As noted in the comments, there *are quite a few* other translation options, depending on context. We would need a little more feedback for a better-tailored translation. My choice of the preposition [**pro**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpro1) (meaning *in favor of*, *in behalf of*, among others), as well as **multis** (from [multus,-a,-um](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmultus)) over pluribus (from plus, -ris, the comparative of multis) is heavily influenced by the words of Jesus in the Last Supper, very well-known to Christians:

> **Bibite ex hoc omnes: hic est enim sanguis meus novi testamenti, qui *pro multis* effunditur in remissionem peccatorum** ([Mt 26:27-28](https://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_nt_evang-matthaeum_lt.html#26))
> *Drink of it, all of you; for this is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out* for many *for the forgiveness of sins* ([Mt 26:27-28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026&version=RSVCE))

Of course, if your intended meaning was different, I will be happy to elaborate.

Comment: Verbum "pro" adicere utrum rectum sit, pendet scilicet e contextu, quem ignoramus. Notabile autem mihi videtur "plures" pro iis, qui mortui sint, i.e. pro mortuis dicere licere, velut "ad plures penetrare" = mori (Plautus, Trinummus 2, 2).

Comment: Indeed, *pro* only works to mean "on behalf of", which isn't the most likely interpretation of "for the many". If the intention is "for the benefit of", as in a donation, then you need the Dative.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Would "pro illis" or "pro multis" have been correct? The "plures pro iis" = "The many, on behalf of these", is clumsy in English, what about Latin? Why did you change "mortui sunt" to perfect subjunctive, "mortui sint"?

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian "To signify a standing before or in front of, for defence or protection; hence an **acting for, in behalf of, in favor of, for the benefit of**, on the side of (opp. contra, adversum): “veri inveniendi causā contra omnia dici oportere et pro omnibus,” Cic. Ac. 2, 18, 60;" Straight from Lewis and Short.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel, thanks for you feedbak, I updated my answer to take it into account, explaining also my choice of words, given the lack of context

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian, the last comment also applies to you. It is just that I think user tags don't work twice in a comment.

Comment: @cmw It's often difficult to grasp what L&S mean, esp. for a native speaker, so I'll illustrate: *prō multīs dōnāre* "to give on behalf of many = the many give"; *multīs dōnāre* "to give to many = the many receive"; *contrā plūribus dōnāre* - nonsensical. *prō plūribus pugnāre* "to fight for the many", *contrā plūribus pugnāre* "to fight against the many", *plūribus pugnāre* - nonsensical. *sanguīs prō plūribus effunditur* "on behalf of, so that they don't have to", *plūribus* "they receive it". So a dedicatory inscription will read *frātrī suō, plūribus, populō Rōmānō* etc., not *prō.*

Comment: @tony I was trying to express "you can say 'plures' for those who died." I wanted to play around a bit with *pro*, not sure if it works. *sint* was subjunctive because of the indirect speech context, one might be able/ prefer to use the indicative here, again not sure. I'm not a Roman, don't take my little Latin exercises too seriously 

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Where did OP say that it was a dedication? In any case, you might want to re-read that Cicero quote a little more carefully.

Comment: @cmw I would ask for a less rhetorical tone. If you re-read my initial comment, you'll see that I didn't claim that the OP said anything of the sort - I said that a gift or dedication seemed to me as the most likely interpretation. I was pointing out that Latin makes a contrast that English doesn't. This is what you replied to, and I explained that your reply is not a counter-example to what I meant but an illustration.—Please take the time to explain what you think it is that I need to notice in the quote instead of suggesting a lack of attention on my part, which reads like a personal remark